# Raspberry Pi Windows 8.1: PHP and python layout

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi

I'm attempting to make a login script that will involve a MYSQL Database from xxamp along with PHP and Python combined, so if a user enters a password correctly, it will run a command "sudo python3 blink.py" or the script itself:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO         ## Import GPIO Library
import time                     ## Import 'time' library (for 'sleep')

pin = 7                         ## We're working with pin 7
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)        ## Use BOARD pin numbering
GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)       ## Set pin 7 to OUTPUT

while True:         ## Repeat 20 times
    GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.HIGH) ## Turn on GPIO pin (HIGH)
    time.sleep(0.1)               ## Wait 1 second
    GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)  ## Turn off GPIO pin (LOW)
    time.sleep(0.1)               ## Wait 1 second

GPIO.cleanup()                  ## Cleanup
```

I'm not entirely sure if this is possible? Can i do something like this

```
<?php
##Php code

if session == "True"

##python script here

?>
```